# user,hostname shown two times in terminal after ssh

Tags: ssh, fedora, prompt

After accessing the remote server through ssh, my konsole,terminal shows like this. User and hostname are shown two times.

```
user@vps:~[user@vps ~]$
```

what might be the issue? currently, i'm on fedora 25

Comment: Can you post the results of:
`echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: Did you set `PS1="something$PS1"`?

Comment: echo $PS1 shows [\u@\h \W]\$

Comment: If you do `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '` (in the interactive shell), does that make it ok?

Comment: I've tried that too but the issue is same.

Comment: Perhaps this article is related? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162857

Comment: do you have a `$PROMPT_COMMAND` set?

Comment: `[bdn@murchunga ~]$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`     
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"

Comment: Ding, ding, ding. There's your culprit. `PROMPT_COMMAND`. `unset` that and it'll be fixed. Good catch @JeffSchaller

Comment: finally, an issue has been solved. :D Thanks @JeffSchaller and everyone.

Comment: It seems like the problem hasn't been solved. I've faced the same issue again though I've already unset PROMPT_COMMAND And not the only ssh, while switching to another user same issue found.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the system's default `bash` initialization files is setting up the environment with (something like)

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='"\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
```

This means that before each primary prompt, that command will be executed, which I must agree is most unfortunate as the prompt should be displayed by `$PS1` and not `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Adding your own definition of `$PS1` to that will cause a "double prompt".

The solution, for a single user, is to unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `~/.bashrc` on the server with

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

The system-wide solution would include finding the shell initialization file that sets this variable and either delete or comment out that line.

The files that may be interesting to look in are

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`

... and possibly other files under `/etc` that are sourced from these. Also, consult the "INVOCATION" section in the `bash` manual on your system to see what other files are used to initialize `bash` there.

Comment: Double prompt problem while switching to another user of the same host has been solved but still while doing ssh, it still shows 2 prompt. But if I unset PROMPT_COMMAND  on the remote host after ssh then the normal prompt is shown.